# Using Except on Dictionaries with Object as Value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, except

until now i had 2 dictionaries of type `Dictionary<string, int>` and needed to get everything which is in `dict1` but not in `dict2` using `except`. Example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "aaa", 1 },
    { "bbb", 2 }
};

Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "aaa", 2 },
    { "bbb", 2 }
};

var newDict = dict1.Except(dict2);
```

`newDict` now contains { "aaa", 1 } which is what i expect, because the value is different.

My problem is, that we needed an additional value in the dictionary so we changed `Dictionary<string, int>` to `Dictionary<string, MyObject>`. When i use `except` now, i don't get the result i'd like to. Example:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(string name, int someNumber)
    {
        myString = name;
        myInt = someNumber;
    }

    public string myString { get; set; }
    public int myInt { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, MyObject> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>
        {
            { "aaa", new MyObject("abc", 1) },
            { "bbb", new MyObject("def", 2) }
        };

        Dictionary<string, MyObject> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>
        {
            { "aaa", new MyObject("abc", 2) },
            { "bbb", new MyObject("def", 2) }
        };

        var newDict = dict1.Except(dict2);
    }
}
```

`newDict` now contains all kvp from dict1, but i actually only want to have the first entry from dict1. I think that is because values of MyObject are not being compared. What can i do to solve this? Is there maybe an easy way via Linq?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `KeyValuePair<TKey,TVal>` uses [`ValueType.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare two dictionary-items. That works if `TKey` and `TValue` are value types. If one of both are reference types both must be the same reference, otherwise `Equals` returns `false`. Since you have two different instances(the `new MyObject...`) they are not equal.

Comment: Override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` in `MyObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `object.Equals(object other)` in your `MyObject`.

Depending on how you define equality between your objects, it could look like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if(!(other is MyObject))
    {
        return false;
    }
    var o = other as MyObject;
    return myString.Equals(o.myString) && myInt == o.myInt;
}
```

As René says in the comment, it usually is a good idea to also implement `GetHashCode` when you implement `Equals`.

Comment: You'll need to overwrite `GetHashCode()`, too. Otherwise all objects will still be regarded different.

Comment: No, they won't. Tested it locally and it works with just `Equals`. Though I agree that it's certainly cleaner to implement `GetHashCode` as well. Don't you need the hash code only if you use the objects as keys in a dictionary?

Comment: @germi: the reason for this is interesting. [`ValueType.GetHashCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) just returns the hashcode of the first non-static field in that type which is the key in a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`. That makes sense for performance reasons. `Equals` can then check if also the value is equal. Found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,328f227c941517bf) and [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/keyvaluepair.cs,8585965bb176a426,references).

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you for the explanation. I was just digging through the reference source to figure it out and got confused and forgot that we still compare `KeyValuePair<>` and not `MyObject`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you! I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals` for your `MyObject` class or use a custom equality comparer for `KeyValuePair<string,MyObject>`:

```
public class MyObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string,MyObject>>
{
   public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, MyObject> obj1, KeyValuePair<string, MyObject> obj2)
   {
        if (obj1 == null) return obj2 == null;
        if (obj2 == null) return false;

        if (obj1.Key != obj2.Key) return false;

        if (obj1.Value == null) return obj2.Value == null;
        if (obj2.Value == null) return false;

        return obj1.Value.myInt == obj2.Value.myInt && 
               obj1.Value.myString == obj2.Value.myString;
   }
   public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
   {
       if (obj == null) return 0;
       int hash = obj.Key.GetHashCode();
       if (obj.Value == null) return hash;
       return hash ^ obj.Value.myInt.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Value.myString.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

And now pass this comparer to `Except()`:

```
var newDict = dict1.Except(dict2, new MyObjectComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = dObject.Where(x=> x.key != "ex").ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value.ToString());
```